# Moving window with wmCtrl results in inaccurate positioning

Tags: bash, x11

Using: Linux Mint 13 (Maya) 64 Cinnamon 2.0.14, wmctrl v. 1.07

Due to a physical disability I'd like to be able to move and resize windows using the keyboard but for the resize and move jumps to be much larger than the tiny increments that is achieved by using the standard move and resize keyboard controls.

To achieve this I've written a Bash script which, depending on the argument given to it, will grow or shrink the window width or height or move the window up, down, left, or right. The script is called by various global Cinnamon hotkeys each calling the script with a different argument.

Resizing the window with wmctrl, either increasing or decreasing the height or width, works perfectly. No problem there.

The problem I've got is when I move the window up, down, left, or right. When I move the window up or down with wmctrl the window will also move slightly left, and when moved left or right the window will also move slightly up. Also the movement value of 100 pixels is not honoured.

```
Values are: x, y, width, height.

XPOS_LEFT
WmCtrl (before move) : 560, 291, 795, 681
WmCtrl (after move)  : 463, 283, 795, 681 [-97, -8] should be [-100, 0]

XPOS_RIGHT
WmCtrl (before move) : 764, 289, 795, 681
WmCtrl (after move)  : 867, 281, 795, 681 [+103, -8] should be [+100, 0]

YPOS_UP
WmCtrl (before move) : 770, 273, 795, 681
WmCtrl (after move)  : 763, 197, 795, 681 [-7, -76] should be [0, -100]

YPOS_DOWN
WmCtrl (before move) : 763, 197, 795, 681
WmCtrl (after move)  : 756, 321, 795, 681 [-7, +124] should be [0, +100]

Growing and shrinking the width and height work perfectly.
```

Initially I thought the problem might be the with the initial window position values that I was retrieving using wmctrl. So I wrote code to retrieve the window's position using xwininfo. For some reason the x,y position values retrieved using wmctrl and xwininfo are very slightly different but the amounts moved in error remain the same and it doesn't make any difference whether I use the wmctrl or xwininfo initial position values - the same problem persists by the same amounts.

Please note that I'm using -1 values for wmctrl -e to indicate do not change, the situation is not resolved by using "-e 0,$xPos,$yPos,$width,$height" in fact doing so makes things much worse because when resizing the window the position of the window changes with a similar problem.

Manually compensating by adding or subtracting an additional 3 for XPOS_LEFT and XPOS_RIGHT and by adding or subtracting an additional 24 for YPOS_UP and YPOS_DOWN gets the movement value to 100, as it should be. But the -8 and -7 in the opposite axis persist when +8 or +7 are added to the appropriate xPos or yPos value and changing the wmctrl command to use "-e 0,$xPos,$yPos,-1,-1".

Can someone explain to me what's happening and how I can fix this please?

Many thanks.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# commandArg ($1) can have any of the following values:
# HEIGHT_GROW, HEIGHT_SHRINK, WIDTH_GROW, WIDTH_SHRINK,
# YPOS_UP, YPOS_DOWN, XPOS_LEFT, XPOS_RIGHT
commandArg="$1"

amountToResize="50"
amountToMove="100"

# Get Window ID of the currently active window using xprop.
winID=$(xprop -root '_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW' | grep --only-matching '0x.*')

# Alter $winID for usage with wmctrl because it requires a leading 0
# in the hex number. e.g. 0x2600006 --> 0x02600006
winIDForWmCtrl=$(echo $winID | sed 's/^0x/0x0/g')

# Get position and dimensions using wmctrl.
xPos=$(wmctrl -G -l | grep $winIDForWmCtrl | awk '{ print $3 }')
yPos=$(wmctrl -G -l | grep $winIDForWmCtrl | awk '{ print $4 }')
width=$(wmctrl -G -l | grep $winIDForWmCtrl | awk '{ print $5 }')
height=$(wmctrl -G -l | grep $winIDForWmCtrl | awk '{ print $6 }')

# Alter the appropriate dimension or positional value and call wmctrl,
# depending of which argument was used when calling the script.

if [ "$commandArg" = "HEIGHT_GROW" ]; then
    let 'height = height + amountToResize'
    wmctrl -ir $winIDForWmCtrl -e 0,-1,-1,-1,$height

elif [ "$commandArg" = "HEIGHT_SHRINK" ]; then
    let 'height = height - amountToResize'
    wmctrl -ir $winIDForWmCtrl -e 0,-1,-1,-1,$height

elif [ "$commandArg" = "WIDTH_GROW" ]; then
    let 'width = width + amountToResize'
    wmctrl -ir $winIDForWmCtrl -e 0,-1,-1,$width,-1

elif [ "$commandArg" = "WIDTH_SHRINK" ]; then
    let 'width = width - amountToResize'
    wmctrl -ir $winIDForWmCtrl -e 0,-1,-1,$width,-1

elif [ "$commandArg" = "YPOS_UP" ]; then
    let 'yPos = yPos - amountToMove'
    wmctrl -ir $winIDForWmCtrl -e 0,-1,$yPos,-1,-1

elif [ "$commandArg" = "YPOS_DOWN" ]; then
    let 'yPos = yPos + amountToMove'
    wmctrl -ir $winIDForWmCtrl -e 0,-1,$yPos,-1,-1

elif [ "$commandArg" = "XPOS_LEFT" ]; then
    let 'xPos = xPos - amountToMove'
    wmctrl -ir $winIDForWmCtrl -e 0,$xPos,-1,-1,-1

elif [ "$commandArg" = "XPOS_RIGHT" ]; then
    let 'xPos = xPos + amountToMove'
    wmctrl -ir $winIDForWmCtrl -e 0,$xPos,-1,-1,-1
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Need to look into this more but at a guess I bet your seeing offsets of your window manager's frames because you are getting the raw size of the client window.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest filing bugs with cinnamon about letting the increments be controllable and probably look into the tiling/grid support that I saw mentioned while I was looking into cinnamon just now.

Comment: Take a maximized window and determine its coordinates with wmctrl. Is the top-left corner sitting at (0,0)? If yes, wmctrl doesn't take WM decorations into account. Now try moving some window to (0,0). Did it move the top-left corner of the WM  frame to (0,0), or the top-left corner of the client area? There may be a discrepancy here. If that's the case, file a bug with wmctrl. You may work around the problem by using `xwininfo` which lets you to select whether you want the WM frame or not (the `-frame` argument).

Comment: If I run xwininfo -stats and then again using -frame and grab the width and height both times then I can work out the frame size by subtracting one width from the other and likewise with the height. The resulting values correspond exactly with the discrepancy. BUT: man xwininfo -frame "This option causes window manager frames to be considered when manually selecting windows". You can't get the -frame output without manually selecting the window with the mouse - running: "xwininfo -frame -id WinId" just gives you the default (-stats). Is there another way for me to get the frame size? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't know `-frame` doesn't work with `-id`. Try `xprop -id xxx _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS`. You may also try using a parent window (or a parent of a parent, etc), via `xwininfo -tree -id xxx`. That would be the WM frame window you need. Experiment and figure out how many level you need to climb.